# What's the problem in this car counter problem?

Tags: python

You might have seen a strip of cable across the road that the DOT uses to count vehicles passing by that road each day. It counts each change in pressure as an axle. Small (car), medium (pickups and vans) and large (trucks) vehicles have different axle patterns so that the DOT can distinguish what kind of vehicles pass by in addition to the number of each.

Write a program that will emulate this car counter. For this program, there will be a continuous string of characters (split up in 10 lines of 50 characters each) in which “x” will represent space between bumps and the “o” will represent a “bump” of an axle. Small vehicles will have the pattern “oo” surrounded by any number of x’s. Medium vehicles will have the pattern “oxo” surrounded by x’s. Large vehicles will have the pattern “oxoxxooo”. To make it easier, a vehicle will not be split across different lines of data. For example, the following represents 2 small vehicles, followed by 2 medium vehicles, and lastly one large vehicle: xooxxxxooxxxxoxoxxxxoxoxxxxxxxoxoxxoooxxxxxxxxxxxx

Input:

There are 10 lines of data, each 50 characters long.

line1 = “xooxxxxooxxxxoxoxxxxoxoxxxxxxxoxoxxoooxxxxxxxxxxxx”
  line2 = “ooxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
  line3 = “oxoxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
  line4 = “oxoxxoooxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
  line5 = “xxxoxoxxoooxxxxxxoxoxxoooxxxxxxxxoxoxxoooxxxxxxxxx”
  line6 = “xoxoxxoooxxxxxooxxxooxxooxxooxxxxxooxxxxooxxxxooxx”
  line7 = “oxoxxoxoxxoxoxxoxoxxoxoxxxxxxxoxoxxxxxoxoxxxxxoxox”
  line8 = “xooxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxoo”
  line9 = “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”
  line10 = “xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxoxoxxooo”

Output:

12 small
  11 medium
  7 large

Here's what I've got so far but I couldn't print the output I wanted:

```
lines = [line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7, line8, line9, line10]
for line in lines:
    scount = line.count('xoox')
    mcount = line.count('xoxox')
    lcount = line.count('oxoxxooo')
    print scount,"small"
    print mcount,"medium"
    print lcount,"large"
```

I have some formatting issue here, all lines in Input and Output should be single line spaced.

Comment: Are you basically asking us to complete your assignment?

Comment: I am sorry if this offended you but I really need some help as I have worked on this all day and I really need to finish it by today. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Doing homework for others is not what SO is for, but since you've at least provided a snippet of what you've tried I will give you some tips. Think about the fact that the lines can start with e.g. just `oox` or end with `xoo`, they won't be caught by `line.count("xoox")`. Look at the lines carefully and apply more code logic. Another thing, declare your count variables outside the loop and use `+=` so they don't get overwritten with each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good application of regular expressions.  Also, the Counter object from the collection modules will help with the tally:

```
  import re
  from collections import Counter
  size    = {"oo":"Small", "oxo":"Medium", "oxoxxooo":"Large"}
  pattern = re.compile("(oxoxxooo|oxo|oo)")
  def countVehicules(bumps): return Counter(size[p] for p in pattern.findall(bumps))

  lines = [line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7, line8, line9, line10]

  for vehicule,count in countVehicules(".".join(lines)).items(): 
      print(count,vehicule)
```

Since this is a homework I'll let you figure out how it works :)

[EDIT] here's a more basic implementation without using imported modules:

```
  lines = [line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7, line8, line9, line10]
  small  = 0
  medium = 0
  large  = 0
  for line in lines:
      firstAxle = 0
      while firstAxle < len(line):
         if line[firstAxle:].startswith("oxoxxooo"):
            large += 1
            firstAxle += 7
         elif line[firstAxle:].startswith("oxo"):
            medium += 1
            firstAxle += 2
         elif line[firstAxle:].startswith("oo"):
            small += 1
         firstAxle += 1
  print(small,"small")
  print(medium,"medium")
  print(large,"large")
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like this is what I needed, but I was wondering if there's any simpler way to code it as I am not familiar with what you're showing here? If there's no other way, can you teach me how to print the output exactly as follows? 

12 small

11 medium

7 large

Comment: Awesome! The more basic implementation should be what I needed. Thank you so much!